# Error in compiling a form after saving it

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have oracle form that is working fine on server , when i download the fmb file and do anything in the form like saving it on oracle form builder then compiling it on server it gives me error on compiling it .

what would be the reason of error ?

Comment: Doesn't the error you get while compiling it on the server reveal the reason?

Comment: @Littlefoot no , just this message
 Compilation errors have occurred.

Comment: How do you compile it on server?

Comment: I compile on ftp server using it's command

frmcmp_batch userid=apps/cloneerp2 module=/ora/oracle/PROD/apps/apps_st/appl/au/12.0.0/forms/US/form_name.fmb output_file=/ora/oracle/PROD/apps/apps_st/appl/au/12.0.0/forms/US/form_name.fmx module_type=form compile_all=special

Comment: Does `batch=yes` parameter help? It is supposed to display messages on the screen.

Comment: where can i use this parameter ?

Comment: It is one of FRMCMP's parameters.

Comment: sorry but i can not find it !

Comment: Find *where*? You *name it*, not *search* for it. `frmcmp userid=un/pw module=x.fmb output_file=x.fmx module_type=form compile_all=yes batch=yes`

Comment: when i tried it i got nothing !

Comment: No further ideas, sorry. I hope that someone else will be able to assist.

Comment: I have a question if you know about it , (app_exception.disabled must be declared ) , (app_window.close_first_window must be declared) , do you know about these errors ?

Comment: Looks like `app_exception` and `app_window` are packages, while `disabled` and `close_first_window` are procedures that belong to them (respectively). The error probably means that you don't have privileges to access those procedures, so you might need to be granted the `execute` privilege on those packages.

Comment: @Littlefoot i have solved the problem , it was about forms_path variable in registry .

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it! Thank you for letting us know.